# How to list all database names from SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying this code in controller but it doesn't work ...

```
Server myserver = new Server(".");
DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();

DatabaseCollection mydata = myserver.Databases;

foreach (Database db in myserver.Databases)
{

}
```

Comment: I really didnt understand the question :S

Comment: Perhaps you want to show more codes? What do you expect, and what do you get when you say it "doesn't work"? That would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply invoke this query from mvc writing c# code and get the databases:

```
SELECT name from sys.databases
```

Otherwise you can add below assembly references from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\` path first.

> 1. Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
> 2. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
> 3. Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

then you can write this code to query databases:

```
var s = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("<your server name>");
List<string> alldatabases = new List<string>();
foreach (Database db in s.Databases) {
   alldatabases.Add(db.Name);
}
```